# Is it possible to trigger an API Gateway endpoint from other account without Credentials in the request into AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is a very confusing question and I'm going to do my best to explain what I need.

I have a project running in and AWS account, let's call it **ProjectA** in the **AccountA**, I developed an API Gateway in the other account, let's call it **AccountB**.

I already added **AccountA** as a trusted account in the **AccountB**, so it should be able to trigger the API gateway without any problem, but that means that I'd need to modify **ProjectA** to include the AWS Credentials in the request (Secret key, AccessKey)

But, It is a pretty old project, and modify it can be pretty challenging.

Before going that path, I'd like to know if there's a way that I can protect my API Gateway in **AccountB**, so it can be trigger from **ProjectA** but without the need of including the security tokens inside the request, and without making it totally public.

Is it possible to do it? Like, make some IAM policies in both accounts that can communicate between them without the need for credentials.

Comment: Is it private API? If yes, you could setup vpc peering connection between the two accounts, so Account B can privately access the API in Account A.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, yes, the API Gateway right now is private

Comment: So you should have interface endpoint for your API your vpc. Maybe can look into cross-account peering of Accounts A and B then. This way could control access the the interface endpoint, and subsequently to the API, by means of VPCs and interface's access policies.